# when back if previous page is x go another page framework7/cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, html-framework-7

i want when back and my previous page is x name, app go to another page. or if previous page is login exit app. 
i write this code but not working

```
$(document).on('page:beforeout', function (e){
    var pre_name = $('.page-previous').data('name');
    if(pre_name == 'neworder' || pre_name == 'index'){
        app.views.main.router.navigate('/home/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might not be working because you are attaching to **before**out. So the page you are leaving is not yet marked as previous.

Anyway, I would recommend to use [`beforeEnter`](https://framework7.io/docs/routes.html#route-before-enter-leave) method for that.